# Reading from InputStream - non-blocking with busy waiting VS blocking with timeout?

Tags: java, inputstream, blocking, nonblocking

The task is to read from InputStream and wait for the result up to a configurable amount of time.

Given two options, which one is preferable? Or suggest another one.

1. blocking call to read() method which you have to timeout yourself
2. non-blocking call to available(), which you have to poll using busy waiting with sleep

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.util.concurrent.*;

   public class MyClass {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
           MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
           final InputStream in = System.in;
           final long timeout = 1000;

           final int result = myClass.blockingWithTimeout(in, timeout);
           //  final int result = myClass.nonBlockingBusyWait(in, timeout);

           System.out.println("Result " + result);
       }

       public int nonBlockingBusyWait(final InputStream is, long timeoutMs) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
           while (is.available() == 0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() < start + timeoutMs)) {
               Thread.sleep(1);
           }
           if (is.available() == 0) {
               return -1;
           } else {
               return is.read();
           }
       }

       public int blockingWithTimeout(final InputStream is, long timeoutMs) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
           ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
           Future<Integer> future = es.submit((Callable<Integer>) is::read);
           try {
               return future.get(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

           } catch (TimeoutException e) {
               return -1;
           } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
               throw e;
           } finally {
               future.cancel(true);
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Don't use `available()`. It's behavior unspecified by the standard in case of EOF

Comment: Don't ever compare `currentTimeMillis()`. Always subtract the deadline and compare with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods have flaws. When using `available()` your program may hang forever in case of EOF. When submitting a blocking `read()`, there's a chance that the background call will complete and consume data from the stream *after* the timeout. Therefore the data will be lost.

When your stream is a socket stream you can set a socket timeout and process `SocketTimeoutException` in your code. Modern Java also provides asynchronous API for non-socket I/O types. You can call its methods returning `Future`. However, if you decide to cancel or abandon the Future, the channel may be marked as inconsistent and refuse further operation.

If it's some old 3rd-party API that returns a blackbox InputStream you can use my wrapper to get socket-like behavior. It saves bytes you don't consume in the internal buffer: https://gist.github.com/basinilya/a5392de106cd890a28742960bcc5cf8c